# ASP.NET Identity in wrong database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-identity

Im using Entity Framework Database first to create a website in ASP.NET on Visual Studio 2015. After creating the database, Visual Studio made a template MVC website for me to edit which had Authentication in it. It uses Identity. I'm now realizing that Identity is storing it's tables in a different database than the one that the tables I made are stored in. When I change the target database for identity, on running the site I get an error saying that Application Users are not in my model.

Is there a way to move Identity to `mydatabase` instead of `defaultconnection` and update my model automatically?

Answer (score 0):

`Identity` uses `localdb` as a default storage. If you want to use another machine for data storing you can try to change only connection string and also check if `SQLExpress` or higher version of `MS SQL` is installed on that machine and don't forget the o run your migrations script (just to be sure you have all necessary tables), but I'm not sure it will work.

If you want to use another db storage (`MySQL` or `SQLite` for example) you **have to implement** your own provider for `Identity` because default Microsoft implementation uses `MS SQL` database and as I said above it relies on `localdb`. `Identity` is also uses `EntityFramework` inside so it won't be difficult. If you decide to do that you can see example on [github](https://github.com/darklektor/ASP.NET-Identity-SQLite-EntityFramework). It's very simple and based on `One user - one role` model

Hope that helps